# Use array of composite type as function parameter and access it

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, array, functions, composite-types

I have created a type `Books` in Postgres which has 2 `numeric` fields and 2 `varchar` fields. I want to send an array of `Books` to a function to `INSERT` those values in a matching table.

This is my type:

```
CREATE TYPE Books AS (
V_Book_ID NUMERIC,
V_Row_Num NUMERIC,
V_Book_OWNER TEXT,
V_Book_OWNER_ID TEXT
);
```

This is my function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Update_Table(row_book Books[]) RETURNS TEXT AS $$
DECLARE
   Status TEXT;
   I_Max integer := array_length(row_book, 1);
BEGIN
FOR I in 1..I_Max
  LOOP
   INSERT INTO books_table(Book_ID,
   Row_Num,
   Book_OWNER,
   Book_OWNER_ID)
   values
   (row_book[I].V_Book_ID,
   row_book[I].V_Row_Num,
   row_book[I].V_Book_OWNER,
   row_book[I].V_Book_OWNER_ID);
END LOOP;

   STATUS:='Saved';
exception when others then
   STATUS:='failure';
   RETURN STATUS;

END;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

How do I send data to the function or how should I call the function with data?

Answer (score 9):

I answered a similar question on SO some time ago, to suggest the same solution with `unnest()` like @a_horse did:

- [Array of composite type as stored procedure input](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19242463/939860)

If `books_table` has the same row type as your composite type `books`, you do not need to create the additional type at all, just use the row type of the table:

```
CREATE TABLE books_table (
  book_id numeric
, row_num numeric
, book_owner text
, book_owner_id text
);
```

#### PL/pgSQL function

If you *need* a plpgsql function for some undeclared reason:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_table_variadic(VARIADIC _books_arr books_table[])
  RETURNS TEXT
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   b books_table;
BEGIN
   FOREACH b IN ARRAY _books_arr
   LOOP
      INSERT INTO books_table  -- rare case where column list is no improvement
      SELECT b.*;
   END LOOP;

   RETURN 'Saved';

EXCEPTION WHEN others THEN
   RETURN 'Failure';
END
$func$;
```

Example call with list of row values:

```
SELECT update_table_variadic('(2,100,Arthur,1)', '(2,50,Zaphod,1)');
```

Without using `VARIADIC`, the function call would require a single array parameter.

**Either** an **array literal** (optionally with explicit cast):

```
SELECT update_table('{"(1,100,Arthur,1)","(1,50,Zaphod,1)"}'::books_table[]);
```

See:

- [How to call PostgreSQL function with array of rowtype as parameter from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24595977/939860)
- [How to pass custom type array to Postgres function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17840058/939860)

**Or** you can use an **array constructor** like [@a_horse demonstrates](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/131506/3684).
Array literals are often easier to provide.

**Major points:**

Use the simpler **`FOREACH`** to loop over an array. See:

- [Postgres - array for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9784986/939860)

Avoid CaMeL-case names in Postgres unless you know what you are doing.

(Optionally) use a **`VARIADIC`** parameter to simplify the syntax for the function call. Then you can provide a *list* of row values. Note the maximum number of function parameters (default 100) if you go with `VARIADIC`:

- [Select rows such that names match elements of input array for pgsql function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17978831/939860)

#### SQL function

If you don't need to catch the exception, and you also don't need the string 'Saved' / 'Failure' to be returned, simplify:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_table_set(VARIADIC _books_arr books_table[])
  RETURNS void
  LANGUAGE sql AS
$func$
   INSERT INTO books_table
   SELECT * FROM unnest(_books_arr) b;
$func$;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=812968fc23a661c788dd98e510af9d00)*
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/c578c/1)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

To create an array of a type, use an explicit array constructor:

```
array[(1,100,'Arthur',1), (1,50,'Zaphod',1)]::books[]
```

So to call your function you would need to use:

```
select update_table(array[(1,100,'Arthur',1), (1,50,'Zaphod',1)]::books[])
```

But your function has an error: after the loop you are missing a return statement, because the one in the exception block is **only** executed *if* an exception occurs.

So you need something like this:

```
begin 

  .... 

  STATUS:='Saved';
  return status;  ---<<< this is missing

  exception when others then
    STATUS:='failure';
    RETURN STATUS; --<<< this is only execute if an exception occurs

END;
```

Alternatively you need another `begin .. end;` block:

```
begin 

  begin    
    for ... 
    end loop;

    STATUS:='Saved';

  exception when others then
    STATUS:='failure';
  end;

  RETURN STATUS; 
END;
```

---

Unrelated, but: you don't need the loop to iterate over the array. You can do that more efficiently using a single statement:

```
INSERT INTO books_table 
   (Book_ID, Row_Num, Book_OWNER, Book_OWNER_ID)
select *
from unnest(row_book);
```