# optimize a 'having count (distinct ) ' query for big data

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I have below query that I need to run on a table with 100million records but it's extremely slow (been running for 5 hours so far)

I am not sure how to optimize it, would be grateful for any help.

The table has an index on DID and week_no, and contains several other columns not indexed, and a primary key (id) indexed

```
DELETE FROM test 
WHERE "DID" IN (SELECT "DID" 
                FROM test 
                GROUP BY "DID" 
                having count(distinct week_no) < 4 );
```

Comment: MySQL or Postgres? Performance optimizations are highly product specific

Comment: How long does just the select take?

Comment: I might have an idea for a radically faster query. But I kindly ask that you first provide proper information [as instructed here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info) and reply to [my modest request over there](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/246714/get-rows-that-exist-exactly-once-per-day-for-a-given-period#comment487221_246714).

Answer (score 0):

A big part of the performance problem is `DELETE`, which will save the old values in case of a crash or other `ROLLBACK`.

If there is a *composite* `INDEX(DID, week_no)` (in that order), there is *some* hope.  With that index, walk through it a few DIDs at a time.  That is, put the delete in a loop that gradually increases `DID`.

See [*this*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks) for discussion of ways to do the walking, especial with a composite index.

The overall time taken by chunking may actually be less, but it will still be a long time.  If you need to run this query frequently, let's discuss other techniques to prepare for the need.